# Having a list of lists - how to get the index of a list containing an item?

Tags: python, list

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

I would like to get `0` for `1`,`2` and `3` and to get `1` for `4`, `5` and `6`.

of course I can do something like that:

```
def get_index(my_list, my_item):
    for i, j in enumerate(my_list):
        if my_item in j:
            return i
    raise ValueError("Item not in any list")
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: I think there's little room for improvement in your solution.

Comment: Isn't there a nice Python one-liner?

Comment: `next(i for i,j in enumerate(a) if my_item in j)` is a one-liner, but it raises `StopIteration` instead on failure, and so your error message is better.  You could add a default value of `None` or something, but I think I still prefer your solution.  If you're doing this multiple times though it'd probably be better to build an index dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

This is an improved version of my original answer, thanks to input from zenply, the OP.

```
b = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,4,5], [4,7,8]]

def create_dict_2(a):
    my_dict = {}
    for index, sublist in enumerate(a):
        for ele in sublist:
            if not ele in my_dict:
                my_dict[ele] = index
    return my_dict
```

Result:

```
>>> my_dict = create_dict(b)
>>> my_dict[4]
1
>>> my_dict[5]
1
>>> my_dict[1]
0
>>> my_dict[7]
3
```

Comment: This is subtly different from the OP's in the case of duplicate elements; the OP's code returns the index of first occurrence and this returns the last.  [Probably that's not relevant, but it's worth noting.]

Comment: @DSM, Yes, you right, my solution is only the same if all occurrences are unique. Good Point.

Comment: If you loop over `a` in reverse, it should recover the OP's behaviour, I think.

Comment: @Akavall the correct way of correcting the original enswer would be to add `if not ele in my_dict:` before updating the dictionary - this way you also updating the dictionary once and not o(n) times in the worst case.

Comment: @Akavall You could do either `my_dict[ele] = my_dict.get(ele, index)` or `my_dict.setdefault(ele, index)` - saves mucking around with the index

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is more readable, but it does handle the case where there's more than one sublist with the item in it:

```
def get_index(my_list, my_item):
    indices = [i for i, sublist in enumerate(my_list) if my_item in sublist]
    if len(indices) == 1:
        return indices[0]
    raise ValueError("Item not in any list or in multiple lists")
```

Comment: I didn't say it explicitly in the question, but I do prefer getting the first index.

Comment: In that case, you could do it in one line: `[i for i, sublist in enumerate(my_list) if my_item in sublist][0]` although then you get an IndexError if it's not there.